# error message "could not find package 'ros-kinetic-desktop-full'"

Tags: ros, package, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to install ROS both through the terminal and by clicking on the "click here" link.  In both cases I get an error message "could not find package 'ros-kinetic-desktop-full'".

What do I do now?

Thanks for your help.

Zale

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259151/error-message-%22could-not-find-package-%27ros-kinetic-desktop-full%27%22/) by [Zale](https://answers.ros.org/users/30007/zale/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From [this](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) page:

Make sure to run

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

and

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

before running the installation command.

EDIT:

Now that we know that you are on Ubuntu 10.04, we can help you further. Ubuntu 10.04 are officially supported by ROS electric, which you can check out [here](http://wiki.ros.org/electric/Installation/Ubuntu). Of course, electric is long gone, so a better solution would be to [install ROS kinetic from source](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source), but be prepared to have (lots of?) dependency issues since you are using an outdated OS. I would strongly suggest to upgrade your OS if that's possible though.

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2017-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zale](https://answers.ros.org/users/30007/zale/) on 2017-04-13**:
I ran these.

The first of these asked me for my password but then didn't seem to do anything but give me back my command prompt.  The second and third returned information.

Same error message on install attempt. "Unable to locate package"

Thanks for the help, but still no joy

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-04-13**:
This is very weird. What is your OS? Maybe you are not on Ubuntu 16.04?

**Comment by [Zale](https://answers.ros.org/users/30007/zale/) on 2017-04-13**:
No, I am on Ubuntu 16.04  That's not the problem.  I've checked for typos in my commands.  That doesn't seem to be the problem either.

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-04-13**:
What is your OS? You should be on 16.04 to use kinetic.

**Comment by [Zale](https://answers.ros.org/users/30007/zale/) on 2017-04-14**:
Yes, OS 10.04 is my operating system.

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-04-14**:
Check the edited answer.

**Comment by [Zale](https://answers.ros.org/users/30007/zale/) on 2017-04-15**:
Damn, that was a typo.  I am on ubuntu 16.04.  Sorry about that.  Don't know how that slipped past me.